# text of button is clipped, auto layout, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

My purpose is to allow the button to grow in width up to a certain limit so that it can display a long title.Therefore, I am setting the constraint for my button using interace builder like below[image]

However, when I try to run and the result is unexpected :
[image]

Not quite why I am getting this. Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong here. Any comments are welcomed here. Thanks

Comment: You have a width constraint on the upper middle button with "Less than or equal" and a number. Is this number large enough so the button can actually grow? I think it's 60 or 80 - and that may be to small

Comment: yeah you are rite, either 60 or 80 is not enough. I changed it to 600 and it worked.

Comment: I'd suggest, that you don't go "overboard" with 600 - assuming, that your app is portrait only. Go for 320 max, and if you don't want it to look bad, you want to go for not more than 280 (20 border left and right).

Answer (score 0):

Call `sizeToFit` on the button after you set the new title. Your button *is* less than or equal to 60 points wide, so the constraints are satisfied. This method will force the button to resize.

You may also want to try adjusting the content compression priority and the priority on your width constraint - currently the higher priority constraint (your width) will win and then be set as close as possible to its constant value.

Comment: just like Boris Prohaska pointed out either 60 or 80 is not enough. Just made a small change and it worked. also thank you

Comment: Oh I missed that - it should be greater than or equal, surely?